# /usr/bin/install: cannot stat `run': No such file or directory

Tags: linux, cross-compilation, error-handling

Im trying to build embeded software using this [RSDK toolchain](https://github.com/KrabbyPatty/rtl819x-toolchain) but after `make menuconfig` and `make` Im getting following error

```
make[7]: Entering directory `/mnt/hgfs/A/rtl819x-toolchain/users/gdb/gdb-6.8/sim/mips'
/bin/sh ../.././sim/mips/../../mkinstalldirs /mnt/hgfs/A/rtl819x-toolchain/users/gdb/gdb-6.8/../gdb-host/bin
mkdir -p -- /mnt/hgfs/A/rtl819x-toolchain/users/gdb/gdb-6.8/../gdb-host/bin
/bin/sh ../.././sim/mips/../../mkinstalldirs /mnt/hgfs/A/rtl819x-toolchain/users/gdb/gdb-6.8/../gdb-host/lib
n=`echo run | sed 's,^,mips-linux-,'`; \
    /usr/bin/install -c run /mnt/hgfs/A/rtl819x-toolchain/users/gdb/gdb-6.8/../gdb-host/bin/$n
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat `run': No such file or directory
make[7]: *** [install-common] Error 1
make[7]: Leaving directory `/mnt/hgfs/A/rtl819x-toolchain/users/gdb/gdb-6.8/sim/mips'
make[6]: *** [install] Error 1
make[6]: Leaving directory `/mnt/hgfs/A/rtl819x-toolchain/users/gdb/gdb-6.8/sim'
make[5]: *** [install-sim] Error 2
make[5]: Leaving directory `/mnt/hgfs/A/rtl819x-toolchain/users/gdb/gdb-6.8'
make[4]: *** [install] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory `/mnt/hgfs/A/rtl819x-toolchain/users/gdb/gdb-6.8'
make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/mnt/hgfs/A/rtl819x-toolchain/users/gdb'
make[2]: *** [gdb] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/mnt/hgfs/A/rtl819x-toolchain/users'
make[1]: *** [app] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/mnt/hgfs/A/rtl819x-toolchain/users'
make: *** [bins] Error 2
```

What does ***cannot stat `run'*** mean ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cannot stat 'thing'` means that something is expecting a file or directory to exist (in this case, likely a directory called 'run') and is trying to perform an operation on it, only to find it is not there.  The meaning comes from the `stat(1)` system call, which reads the metadata of a link (i. e. a file, directory, socket, symbolic link, etc.) on the filesystem.

Looking at your error log, `install` is an executable (i. e. a script or binary) which is trying do access `run` and it does not exist, causing the error to be thrown.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using `install -m 755 -d $(SRC_DIR) $(INSTALL_DIR)`